# Importing csv file into latex as a table

Tags: tables, import, csv

I am using the \csvautotabular function to import data from a csv file. It has worked beautifully; however, I only want to import certain columns from the file. How can I exclude certain columns?

EDIT:

Okay, here is my csv file:

```
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),Y Position in pixels,Zeroed Y Position in pixels,Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq.,Y Position In Meters using new trans. Eq.
43.97,0,734,528,14.22624,18.26294
44.01,0.04,731,525,14.11335,18.14345
44.04,0.07,729,523,14.03819,18.06389
44.07,0.1,726,520,13.9256,17.9447
44.11,0.14,720,514,13.70096,17.70686
44.14,0.17,718,512,13.62624,17.62774
44.17,0.2,714,508,13.47704,17.46974
44.21,0.24,711,505,13.36535,17.35145
44.24,0.27,706,500,13.1796,17.1547
44.27,0.3,700,494,12.95736,16.91926
44.31,0.34,696,490,12.8096,16.7627
44.34,0.37,690,484,12.58856,16.52846
44.37,0.4,685,479,12.40491,16.33381
44.41,0.44,679,473,12.18519,16.10089
44.44,0.47,672,466,11.92976,15.83006
44.47,0.5,664,458,11.63904,15.52174
44.51,0.54,659,453,11.45799,15.32969
44.54,0.57,651,445,11.16935,15.02345
44.57,0.6,642,436,10.84616,14.68046
44.61,0.64,633,427,10.52459,14.33909
44.64,0.67,625,419,10.24011,14.03701
44.67,0.7,616,410,9.9216,13.6987
44.71,0.74,607,401,9.60471,13.36201
44.74,0.77,597,391,9.25451,12.98981
44.77,0.8,587,381,8.90631,12.61961
44.81,0.84,577,371,8.56011,12.25141
44.84,0.87,567,361,8.21591,11.88521
44.87,0.9,554,348,7.77144,11.41214
44.91,0.94,541,335,7.33035,10.94245
44.94,0.97,528,322,6.89264,10.47614
44.97,1,515,309,6.45831,10.01321
45.01,1.04,503,297,6.06039,9.58889
45.04,1.07,490,284,5.63256,9.13246
45.07,1.1,475,269,5.14311,8.61001
45.11,1.14,458,252,4.59384,8.02334
45.14,1.17,444,238,4.14584,7.54454
45.17,1.2,427,221,3.60711,6.96841
45.21,1.24,410,204,3.07416,6.39806
45.24,1.27,393,187,2.54699,5.83349
45.27,1.3,377,171,2.05611,5.30741
45.31,1.34,361,155,1.57035,4.78645
45.34,1.37,346,140,1.1196,4.3027
45.38,1.41,328,122,0.58464,3.72814
45.41,1.44,309,103,0.02699,3.12869
45.44,1.47,289,83,-0.55221,2.50549
45.48,1.51,269,63,-1.12341,1.89029
45.51,1.54,246,40,-1.7704,1.1927
45.54,1.57,224,18,-2.37936,0.53534
45.58,1.61,203,-3,-2.95161,-0.08311
45.61,1.64,206,0,-2.8704,0.0047
```

The following columns I want to remove: Time (s), Y Position in pixels, Zeroed Y Position in pixels, Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq.

Here is what I have typed in TeXstudio, which doesn't work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Basket_ball.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),Y Position in pixels,Zeroed Y Position in pixels,Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq.,Y Position In Meters using new trans. Eq.
43.97,0,734,528,14.22624,18.26294
44.01,0.04,731,525,14.11335,18.14345
44.04,0.07,729,523,14.03819,18.06389
44.07,0.1,726,520,13.9256,17.9447
44.11,0.14,720,514,13.70096,17.70686
44.14,0.17,718,512,13.62624,17.62774
44.17,0.2,714,508,13.47704,17.46974
44.21,0.24,711,505,13.36535,17.35145
44.24,0.27,706,500,13.1796,17.1547
44.27,0.3,700,494,12.95736,16.91926
44.31,0.34,696,490,12.8096,16.7627
44.34,0.37,690,484,12.58856,16.52846
44.37,0.4,685,479,12.40491,16.33381
44.41,0.44,679,473,12.18519,16.10089
44.44,0.47,672,466,11.92976,15.83006
44.47,0.5,664,458,11.63904,15.52174
44.51,0.54,659,453,11.45799,15.32969
44.54,0.57,651,445,11.16935,15.02345
44.57,0.6,642,436,10.84616,14.68046
44.61,0.64,633,427,10.52459,14.33909
44.64,0.67,625,419,10.24011,14.03701
44.67,0.7,616,410,9.9216,13.6987
44.71,0.74,607,401,9.60471,13.36201
44.74,0.77,597,391,9.25451,12.98981
44.77,0.8,587,381,8.90631,12.61961
44.81,0.84,577,371,8.56011,12.25141
44.84,0.87,567,361,8.21591,11.88521
44.87,0.9,554,348,7.77144,11.41214
44.91,0.94,541,335,7.33035,10.94245
44.94,0.97,528,322,6.89264,10.47614
44.97,1,515,309,6.45831,10.01321
45.01,1.04,503,297,6.06039,9.58889
45.04,1.07,490,284,5.63256,9.13246
45.07,1.1,475,269,5.14311,8.61001
45.11,1.14,458,252,4.59384,8.02334
45.14,1.17,444,238,4.14584,7.54454
45.17,1.2,427,221,3.60711,6.96841
45.21,1.24,410,204,3.07416,6.39806
45.24,1.27,393,187,2.54699,5.83349
45.27,1.3,377,171,2.05611,5.30741
45.31,1.34,361,155,1.57035,4.78645
45.34,1.37,346,140,1.1196,4.3027
45.38,1.41,328,122,0.58464,3.72814
45.41,1.44,309,103,0.02699,3.12869
45.44,1.47,289,83,-0.55221,2.50549
45.48,1.51,269,63,-1.12341,1.89029
45.51,1.54,246,40,-1.7704,1.1927
45.54,1.57,224,18,-2.37936,0.53534
45.58,1.61,203,-3,-2.95161,-0.08311
45.61,1.64,206,0,-2.8704,0.0047
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Theory}


%\csvautotabular{Basket_ball.csv}



\begin{tabular}{| l | r |}\hline%
\bfseries Time (s) & \bfseries Position (m)
\csvreader[head to column names]{Basket_ball.csv}{} % 
{\\\Time (s)\ \Y Position in pixels & \Zeroed Y Position in pixels & \Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq. } % 
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the csvsimple package? It's in page 5 of the manual.

Comment: I found this program awesome: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables

Comment: Here is a script I put together for parsing flat files into latex tables. http://superscripts.co/produce-latex-table-from-csv/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The `csvsimple` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) describes it. This is an modified example from the manual.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}


\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c}%
    \bfseries Person & \bfseries Matr.~No.% specify table head
    \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\\hline\givenname\ \name & \matriculation}% specify your coloumns here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

result is:

[image: result1]

If you have spaces in your header you can't use `head to column names`. So you may use `\csvcoli` etc. Here a quick example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
    
    
\begin{filecontents*}{Basket_ball.csv}
    Time (s),Zeroed time (s),Y Position in pixels,Zeroed Y Position in pixels,Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq.,Y Position In Meters using new trans. Eq.
    43.97,0,734,528,14.22624,18.26294
    44.01,0.04,731,525,14.11335,18.14345
    44.04,0.07,729,523,14.03819,18.06389
    44.07,0.1,726,520,13.9256,17.9447
    44.11,0.14,720,514,13.70096,17.70686
    44.14,0.17,718,512,13.62624,17.62774
    44.17,0.2,714,508,13.47704,17.46974
    44.21,0.24,711,505,13.36535,17.35145
    44.24,0.27,706,500,13.1796,17.1547
    44.27,0.3,700,494,12.95736,16.91926
    44.31,0.34,696,490,12.8096,16.7627
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}



\section*{Theory}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}%
    \textbf{Time (s)} & \textbf{Zeroed time (s)}% specify table head
    \csvreader[head to column names]{Basket_ball.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\\hline\csvcoli&\csvcolii}% specify your coloumns here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: result 2]

Comment: I am not quite sure I see how this would exclude specific columns from my csv file.

Comment: @Mack Please take a look at `grade.csv`. it has a *gender* and a *grade* column that isn't showing up at the actual table. The manual also lists different ways that might fit your specific problem in better way.

Comment: I actually just edited my post, which includes my code that I was trying to make similar to the one you gave in your post.

Comment: @Mack The manual says that `head to column names` can only be used if the header entries do not contain spaces and
special characters. So we need to use a different way. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The `csvcolii` commands specify which column from the `Basket_ball.csv` goes into the column in which position in the table (position of `csvcol..` in the row/line of `csvcol..`). They can be equal to the number of columns specified in `\begin{tabular}{l|l}%` and with `\bfseries Time (s) & \bfseries Zeroed time (s) ` (but not more). The `csvcolii` of the table of the  does not proceed to `csvcoliii` but to `csvcoliv` and `csvcolv` and `csvcolvi` etc.

Comment: After some digging into the manual, I found out that `csvsimple` is also `tsvsimple`: you can provide the `separator=tab` argument (e.g. `\csvreader[separator=tab]` in the above MWE). Nice!

Comment: What if I don't want to specify the columns because I just want the whole table? And how do I make it use the first row as the column headers?

Comment: @Vrangone `\bfseries` is fine to use

Answer (score 33):

You can use `pgfplotstable` or `datatool` which I think `csvsimple` comes from. Here is an example with `pgfplotstable` with default settings.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),Y Position in pixels,Zeroed Y Position in pixels,Y Position in meters using original trans. Eq.,Y Position In Meters using new trans. Eq.
43.97,0,734,528,14.22624,18.26294
44.01,0.04,731,525,14.11335,18.14345
44.04,0.07,729,523,14.03819,18.06389
44.07,0.1,726,520,13.9256,17.9447
44.11,0.14,720,514,13.70096,17.70686
44.14,0.17,718,512,13.62624,17.62774
44.17,0.2,714,508,13.47704,17.46974
44.21,0.24,711,505,13.36535,17.35145
44.24,0.27,706,500,13.1796,17.1547
44.27,0.3,700,494,12.95736,16.91926
44.31,0.34,696,490,12.8096,16.7627
44.34,0.37,690,484,12.58856,16.52846
44.37,0.4,685,479,12.40491,16.33381
44.41,0.44,679,473,12.18519,16.10089
44.44,0.47,672,466,11.92976,15.83006
44.47,0.5,664,458,11.63904,15.52174
44.51,0.54,659,453,11.45799,15.32969
44.54,0.57,651,445,11.16935,15.02345
44.57,0.6,642,436,10.84616,14.68046
44.61,0.64,633,427,10.52459,14.33909
44.64,0.67,625,419,10.24011,14.03701
44.67,0.7,616,410,9.9216,13.6987
44.71,0.74,607,401,9.60471,13.36201
44.74,0.77,597,391,9.25451,12.98981
44.77,0.8,587,381,8.90631,12.61961
44.81,0.84,577,371,8.56011,12.25141
44.84,0.87,567,361,8.21591,11.88521
44.87,0.9,554,348,7.77144,11.41214
44.91,0.94,541,335,7.33035,10.94245
44.94,0.97,528,322,6.89264,10.47614
44.97,1,515,309,6.45831,10.01321
45.01,1.04,503,297,6.06039,9.58889
45.04,1.07,490,284,5.63256,9.13246
45.07,1.1,475,269,5.14311,8.61001
45.11,1.14,458,252,4.59384,8.02334
45.14,1.17,444,238,4.14584,7.54454
45.17,1.2,427,221,3.60711,6.96841
45.21,1.24,410,204,3.07416,6.39806
45.24,1.27,393,187,2.54699,5.83349
45.27,1.3,377,171,2.05611,5.30741
45.31,1.34,361,155,1.57035,4.78645
45.34,1.37,346,140,1.1196,4.3027
45.38,1.41,328,122,0.58464,3.72814
45.41,1.44,309,103,0.02699,3.12869
45.44,1.47,289,83,-0.55221,2.50549
45.48,1.51,269,63,-1.12341,1.89029
45.51,1.54,246,40,-1.7704,1.1927
45.54,1.57,224,18,-2.37936,0.53534
45.58,1.61,203,-3,-2.95161,-0.08311
45.61,1.64,206,0,-2.8704,0.0047
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
     columns={Zeroed time (s),Y Position In Meters using new trans. Eq.},
    ]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit, that this solution is cleaner.

Comment: @someonr I like your honesty, I agree. Thank you guys +1!

Comment: Is it true that `\pgfplotstabletypeset` is limited by default to data containing floats only? You should probably add `[string type ...]` option in order to process csv which contains strings as well.

Answer (score 13):

The service http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ lets you create latex-based tables in a GUI and then export the code.
It also lets you upload a CSV and converts it aut

Comment: I checked now (2019) and could not find an option for upload the csv file.

Comment: @user855443 it's at file -> import csv

Answer (score 6):

An alternative option is to programmatically modify the csv file to produce a LaTeX table with the shell code below. This gives you total control over the formatting of the final table and does not require extra packages. The caveat is that some of the substitutions need to be done carefully to avoid altering the content of the table. In general I find that tsv is more resilient to this kind of issues, since table fields rarely contain `\t` but may contain `,`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Convert table to latex
cat table.csv | sed \
    -e 's:&:\\&:g' \
    -e 's:,:\t\&\t:g' \
    -e 's:"::g' \
    -e 's/_/\\_/g'  \
    -e 's:$:\t\\\\:g' > table.tex

# Latex table syntax
ed table.tex << END
1i
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2  \\\\
\midrule
.
\$a
\hline
\end{tabular}
.
wq
END
```

Note that the actual LaTeX syntax inserted by `ed` needs to be modified for your specific table

Comment: Hm, and can this be used on an windows computer too? How?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple options to get a Unix-type shell on Windows.  You can run it in the shell of the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) that is installed through the Windows app store. An alternative is Cygwin.

Comment: +1 for recommending using `tsv` files.

Answer (score 3):

Use python, specifically [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html).

```
import pandas as pd    
csv_table = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(csv_table.to_latex(index=False))
```

`to_latex` returns a string copy and paste or alternatively you could write it to a file

```
with open("csv_table.tex", 'w') as f:
    f.write(csv_table.to_latex(index=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

To update Irwin's answer:

> The service http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables lets you create latex-based tables in a GUI and then export the code. It also lets you upload a CSV and converts it automatically.

You have to select **"File"->"Import CSV file"** from the GUI. It handles strings and doubles just fine.

Comment: This worked like a charm!