# csv string to table without external files

Tags: csv

I'm trying to create a Latex table from a CSV string.  I saw [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table) , after which I started playing around with the csvsimple package ([manual](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf)).

What I don't understand is the need for `filecontents`.  When something like

```
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
foo,bar,baz
zip,boom,bang
\end{filecontents*}

\csvautotabular{example.csv}
```

is run, this creates a file on disk called example.csv.  Is there a way to parse CSV from the string itself?

```
\csvautotabular{\mymacro}
```

doesnt fly either.

Comment: You don't need the `filecontents` environment to parse CSV files. The `filecontents` is only used to show the example.

Comment: How do you define `\mymacro`?

Comment: `\mymacro` would have just expanded to a comma-separated string, e.g. `a,b,c,d` .  In any case, this seems to be a limitation of csvsimple, so for now I explicitly made files for all my csv strings.