# Creating a table from CSV file with strings?

Tags: tables, csv

I want to create a table from a CSV file in LaTex. I am able to do it with numbers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146729/2956) but creating table for strings such as abbrevions does not work. What is the problem?

[image]

**MVE**

> This example fires error *"Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '...' as a floating point number, sorry."*
>
> ```
> \documentclass{standalone}
> \usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
> \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning
>
> \begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
> Abbreviation, Description
> ACG, Azeri Chirag Guneshli
> bcm, Billion cubic meters
> BTC, Baku Tbilisi Ceyhan
> CIA, Central Intelligence Agency
> Btu, British thermal unit
> CAC, Central Asia Center
> EU, European Union
> LNG, Liquified Natural Gas
> NATO, North Atlantic Treaty Organization
> OMV, Österreichische Mineralölverwaltung
> \end{filecontents*}
>
> \begin{document}
> \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, columns={Abbreviation,Description}]{test.csv}
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: Why don't you use the `csvsimple` solution there rather than the pgf one which expects to be fed mathematical expressions?

Comment: @cfr I did not know that. pgf solution looked so elegant!

Comment: @cfr I tried `csvsimple` and getting other errors: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211395/2956

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `string type` option:

[image]

### Notes:

- To control the alignment of each row you can specify the style for each row.

  ```
  columns/Abbreviation/.style={column type=l},
  columns/Description/.style={column type=l},
  ```

  Alternatively you can set the alignment for *all* columns via `column type=l`.
- To add the horizontal lines, I used [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) and the `every head row` and `every last row` keys.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning


%\usepackage{filecontents}% <-- commented to prevent overwriting fuel
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Abbreviation, Description
ACG, Azeri Chirag Guneshli
bcm, Billion cubic meters
BTC, Baku Tbilisi Ceyhan
CIA, Central Intelligence Agency
Btu, British thermal unit
CAC, Central Asia Center
EU, European Union
LNG, Liquified Natural Gas
NATO, North Atlantic Treaty Organization
OMV, Österreichische Mineralölverwaltung
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type, 
    col sep=comma, 
    columns={Abbreviation,Description},
    columns/Abbreviation/.style={column type=l},
    columns/Description/.style={column type=l},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you +1! How does the positioning (not to center but to right) and adding \hline work?

Comment: @hhh: See revised answer.

Comment: I tried to create a large example of this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211408/how-to-create-a-large-table-with-pgfplots-and-string-entries), can you say why it is not working? Perhaps I don't understand `after row=\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}`? It would be super cool to generate tables fast from CSV files like above with strings, any easy way?

Comment: How to use another names for columns, different from the head of csv file?

Comment: @Sigur: I don't know off hand and suggest you post a new question specifically about that issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a lightly modified version of [someonr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146719/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Abbreviation, Description
ACG, Azeri Chirag Guneshli
bcm, Billion cubic meters
BTC, Baku Tbilisi Ceyhan
CIA, Central Intelligence Agency
Btu, British thermal unit
CAC, Central Asia Center
EU, European Union
LNG, Liquified Natural Gas
NATO, North Atlantic Treaty Organization
OMV, Österreichische Mineralölverwaltung
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}%
      \toprule
      \bfseries Abbreviation & \bfseries Description% specify table head
      \csvreader[%
        head to column names,
        after head=\\\midrule,
        late after line=\\,
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
      {\Abbreviation & \Description}% specify your coloumns here
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

- `head to column names` lets you say `\Abbreviation` and `\Description` rather than using the internal `\csvcoli` etc.
- If you take the rules and new lines out of the main definition, you can tweak the formatting a little better.
- `after head` sets the code for the end of the header line (`\\\midrule`)
- `late after line` sets the code for the end of each row of the tabular (`\\`)
- You can then use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` at the head and foot of the tabular without ending up with either complaints about misplaced align characters or excessive vertical spacing between the last line of the tabular and the final rule.

[image: tabular of abbreviations]

Comment: I cannot understand where you specify Abbreviation and Description to be columns? What are `\csvcoli` and `\csvcolii`? +1 for beautiful format, I still find the pgf thing easier to understand even though it looks uglier...

Comment: Csvcoli possibly csv column one and ii for column 2

Comment: @hhh That is just how `csvsimple` refers to the columns, I think. The `head to column names` is, I think, telling it to match the column headings to the names of the columns. (I haven't read the documentation - I really did just modify the earlier answer.)

Comment: @hhh I've updated the answer with some bits of explanation and to use more expressive macro names. The documentation for `csvsimple` is pretty good and makes a lot more sense of the code ;).