# pgfplotstable with alphabetic characters input from csv

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I'm reproducing an example from [this tutorial](http://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/advanced/lesson-9/). If the **input** from the csv file is **numeric**, it works well. However, if one of the columns of the csv contains **alphabetic characters**, it returns an error message.

I added `string type,` after seeing [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211390/creating-a-table-from-csv-file-with-strings), to no avail.

I've been tinkering a while with it and considered reading the pgfplotstable manual from cover to cover and try to make a custom table from scratch. However, that defeats the purpose of taking advantage of an 'already cooked' example.

Which is the correct way of doing this?

The MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{siunitx} % Formats the units and values
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Generates table from .csv
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}% supress warning

% Setup siunitx:
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
  round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Autogenerated table from .csv file.}
    \label{table1}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
      multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
      col sep=comma, % the seperator in our .csv file
      string type, % Added in hopes of enabling alphabetic input.
      display columns/0/.style={
                column name=$Value 1$, % name of first column
                column type={S},string type},  % use siunitx for formatting
      display columns/1/.style={
                column name=$Value 2$,
                column type={S},string type},
      every head row/.style={
                before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
                after row={
                        \si{\ampere} & \si{\volt}\\ % the units seperated by &
                        \midrule} % rule under units
                        },
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}, % rule at bottom
    ]{table.csv} % filename/path to file
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

My (working) csv input is:

[image: Input file (csv)]

Its output is:

[image]

And I would like to input:

[image: Desired input]

And get an analogous output. i.e. Words in the first column. However, in its current form, it returns the following error, as seen in he [test.log](http://pastebin.com/0TisemP9).

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "duplicate-exponent-token"
! 
! Duplicate exponent marker token '\token_to_str:N e' in input.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.37     ]{table.csv}
                      % filename/path to file
? 
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................  

l.37     ]{table.csv}
                      % filename/path to file
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| Only one exponent marker token can appear in a single number.
|...............................................
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by your use of `column type={S}` for the first column: Using that column type will cause the content of the column to be parsed by `siunitx`, even if you specify `string type` afterwards. `siunitx` then stumbles on the line containing `Three` because it finds two `e`'s, which it takes to be exponent markers. You can fix the problem by removing the `column type={S}`.

A couple more things: If you specify the column names manually (instead of taking them from the first row of your table), you should set `header=false`, otherwise the first line of data will be discarded.

To get proper alignment when using `S` columns, you should also specify the format of your numbers, in this case `S[table-format=1.2e2 ]` (one integer digit, two decimal digits, two exponent digits).

And lastly, to get italic text, never use `$` (that's for maths mode and typesets the words as strings of variables, with awkward spacing), but rather use `\textit`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx} % Formats the units and values
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Generates table from .csv
% Setup siunitx:
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
  round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
      multicolumn names,
      col sep=comma, % the seperator in our .csv file
      string type, % Added in hopes of enabling alphabetic input.
      display columns/0/.style={
                column name=\textit{Value 1}, % name of first column
                string type},  % use siunitx for formatting
      display columns/1/.style={
                column name=\textit{Value 2},
                column type={S[table-format=2.2e2]}}
    ]{
Two,2.00000E+015 
Three,2.000000E+015   
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the suggestions! It works now.

Comment: I face the same problem@CalculusKnight. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed }
\label{tab:Comput}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{5}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Proposed and benchmark forecasting frameworks} \
    \cmidrule{2-6}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{FS-ANN\ Computational \efficiency}}
        & {\thead{Bi-level\ Computational \efficiency}}
            & {\thead{AFC-STLF\ Computational \efficiency}}
                & {\thead{MI-mEDE-ANN\ Computational\efficiency}}
                     & {\thead{FS-FCRBM-GWDO \ Computational \efficiency}} \
\midrule
    Computational complexity (level) & Low & High & Moderate & High & Moderate \

\midrule
%Avg.& 2.12 & 1.79 & 1.44 & 0.410\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}