# I want to insert a file into my lyx document not import

Tags: lyx, csv

I have a lyx file and I want to attach some csv files. I don't want to import the files because most of them are very large tables, rather I would like to so something like what Microsoft word does with the insert Object option:
[image]

when I double click in this icon, the csv file opens.

Step by step:
I choose the csv file.
[image]

This is how it looks like. When I press on the spreadsheet icon this pops up.
[image]

when I press the option to view my lyx file (as a pdf) it tells me that there is no gnumeric to lyx file converter and this error pops:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to insert it through insert-->external material and from the drop-down menu choose spreadsheet?

Comment: I agree with George. Note that you might need to have Gnumeric installed (if you happen to be on Ubuntu, do `sudo apt-get install gnumeric`).

Comment: I did try thtat option however it only supports gnumeric, ods and xls files. And if I choose my csv file it shows the following error when I want to view it :`  ...\input{0C__Users_Aisha_built_pyramids.tex}
                                                   &
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)`

Comment: @George Might you know the solution to this error?

Comment: @Sarahcartenz I just tried with a csv and it worked for me. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz Unfortunately, I am not so familiar with that error. 

Please have a look at this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table

Probably it will give you some info

Comment: @scottkosty are these the same steps you did? As you can see on the edited part of the question, I got 2 errors.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz yes, those are the steps. Do you have Gnumeric installed? Does it work for .xls files? Let's check that before trying .csv.

Comment: @scottkosty I have tried using a xls file but it gave the same error. About installing gnumeric the way you said above, I cant since I cant use sudo (am not a super user).

Comment: @Sarahcartenz I see. Well at least now we know the problem. In this case the question is now about how to install a program locally without super user privileges. I don't have any words of wisdom on this. I'd suggest googling or posting this question in a different forum. But yes it is expected that without gnumeric the above will not work for you.

Comment: @scottkosty Thank you for your time and effort!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem seems to be about installing Gnumeric.