# Error making a spreadsheet inset in LyX - How to make a spreadsheet inset in LyX?

Tags: lyx, open-office

I am running LyX on Windows 10. I made an inset of a spreadsheet called temp.ods, by going *Insert-->File-->External Material...* and then selected the spreadsheet.  I keep encountering the following error when I try to export the file (The name of the file I am exporting is "temp.ods")

> An error occured while running: 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnumeric\1.10.16\bin\ssconvert.exe --export-type=Gnumeric_html:latex "temp.ods" "temp.tex"

In order to make the conversion, LyX needs the Gnumeric file "ssconvert". I installed Gnumeric, and modified the path to the conversion file by going to *Tools-->Preferences-->Converters.* I removed the default converter definition for Gnumeric spreadsheet->LaTeX, and added a new one, with the correct parth to ssconvert.

Related Question:
[I want to insert a file into my lyx document not import](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246808/i-want-to-insert-a-file-into-my-lyx-document-not-import)

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a question?

Comment: I was wondering if there exists an easy way to insert a spreadsheet into a LaTeX document, so that the data in the spreadsheet exports with the LaTeX document automatically. Ideally, I would like a solution that Uses LyX, but LaTeX works too, because LyX is a LaTeX editor. That is: how do I make a spreadsheet inset in a LaTeX (or LyX) document?

Comment: I think this must be a LyX thing. At any rate, I have no idea what you are asking about. I don't even know what the difference between `inset`, `insert` and `import` is. Nor do I understand how you could export an `.ods` file from LyX. But I know zilch about LyX, so that may be to be expected.

Comment: Here is the documentation on inserting a spreadsheet in LyX: https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/SpreadsheetExternalInset

Comment: If you have LyX installed, you should be able to find an example of making a spreadsheet inset under %file path to your lyx installation%Resources\examples\spreadsheet.lyx . When I run this file, I get the error I mentioned in my question. There is no difference between an inset, an insert, and an import, as far as I know; the words are synonymous.