# "Undefined control sequence" while creating a tabular from a csv file

Tags: tables, csvsimple

This issue is to say the least, very weird. I have a 12 columns csv file about several macroeconomics indicators:

```
n,pibreal,pibnom,deflactor,c,isr,trc,tdeflactado,trcdeflactado,I,x,m
2000,1059317580733.46,393302970000,37.127956446,281965700000,10616220000,437870990000,3941585537.81615,162572550457.059,109702668399.757,139614000000,172276800000
2001,1082466050569.29,427319070000,39.4764408339,300954300000,15409220000,447232010000,6083011616.26492,176551279817.895,114396066342.969,136274700000,165030400000
2002,1128392235489.82,477430190000,42.3106589166,335857300000,16166240000,338898720000,6840042666.04618,143390281492.075,128699689772.917,146685700000,181420000000
2003,1110119525916.62,628611040000,56.6255277314,453212600000,19903830000,312522800000,11270648776.2678,176967684781.06,122008139726.167,264978400000,265880500000
2004,1136920845139.83,935984730000,82.3262880614,663061200000,24380340000,278650080000,20071428938.7504,229402267544.141,193068834546.586,385134100000,376302800000
2005,1242447543857.26,1083445000000,87.2024742901,781476100000,29919960000,304195780000,26090945426.6056,265266246846.043,268402600855.057,306952300000,361030100000
2006,1353859075481.57,1261399670000,93.1706772768,903196900000,38954770000,232809480000,36294423040.6312,216910169280.665,339655467614.886,356029000000,448321200000
2007,1455253260300.12,1455253260300.12,100,1028340106626.27,55713270000,187362070000,55713270000,187362070000,413484099269.877,390475504120.436,510886323057.287
2008,1503061927458.95,1656961744055.34,110.2390868789,1215394185261.69,58252840000,162377730000,64217398897.0342,179003726846.707,498715830537.822,397469645748.566,620524420197.88
2009,1513348643542.65,1729468428699.59,114.2808985939,1276354253008.9,54168480000,121031490000,61904225698.6731,138315874353.622,414195624115.801,365381960826.093,509650082429.96
2010,1638697922673.49,1978851884596.09,120.7575757079,1475592123331.43,53750500000,75333100000,64907800730.8705,90970425265.602,527505380784.85,433869092753.816,651040957447.698
2011,1688841703851.69,2218428824292.59,131.3580082274,1233480264844.07,65218700000,11002340000,85669985311.7773,14452454682.4021,556020587537.167,525750765136.529,749797745712.548
2012,1730752476014.56,2377503668802.55,137.3682084383,1786146992638.45,318558732261.06,11832120000,437598423330.748,16253571264.2686,548109131163.141,580512510875.323,786487854482.959
2013,1834292875289.9,2558585610654.53,139.4862099244,1889709894858.51,369413000000,10100470000,515280192667.892,14088762787.5474,558352865212.123,650889248254.709,797757282239.087
2014,1959496848092.36,2786229703801.94,142.1910786187,2018227692393.27,417439800000,,593562154203.741,41485368130.1524,600017741550.596,744803898213.531,874637508968.428
```

I've used a very short tex file to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}%
\bfseries Año & \bfseries PIB & \bfseries Consumo privado%
\csvreader{test.csv}{}%
{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiiii}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

At first I was presuming problems with the headers, so used the `\csvcol` command instead of declaring the column names, the same result.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\csv@@body ...csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiiii 

l.10 ...line \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiiii}
                                                  %
? x
```

The complete log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.11.17)  16 MAY 2016 21:29
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 5 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csvsimple/csvsimple.sty
Package: csvsimple 2014/07/14 version 1.12 LaTeX CSV file processing

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks14
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks16
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\csv@file=\read1
\c@csvinputline=\count87
\c@csvrow=\count88
\c@csvcol=\count89
\csv@out=\write3
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
Missing character: There is no � in font cmbx10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmbx10!

! Undefined control sequence.
\csv@@body ...csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiiii 

l.10 ...line \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiiii}
                                                  %
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1148 strings out of 494903
 26707 string characters out of 6179138
 73889 words of memory out of 5000000
 4498 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 40 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,6n,46p,272b,210s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

The examples on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146719/33619) are built without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want columns 1, 3 and 5, which are given by `\csvcoli`, `\csvcoliii` and `\csvcolv`, respectively (using roman conversion of numbers). So, not `\csvcoliiiii`, but `\csvcolv`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
n,pibreal,pibnom,deflactor,c,isr,trc,tdeflactado,trcdeflactado,I,x,m
2000,1059317580733.46,393302970000,37.127956446,281965700000,10616220000,437870990000,3941585537.81615,162572550457.059,109702668399.757,139614000000,172276800000
2001,1082466050569.29,427319070000,39.4764408339,300954300000,15409220000,447232010000,6083011616.26492,176551279817.895,114396066342.969,136274700000,165030400000
2002,1128392235489.82,477430190000,42.3106589166,335857300000,16166240000,338898720000,6840042666.04618,143390281492.075,128699689772.917,146685700000,181420000000
2003,1110119525916.62,628611040000,56.6255277314,453212600000,19903830000,312522800000,11270648776.2678,176967684781.06,122008139726.167,264978400000,265880500000
2004,1136920845139.83,935984730000,82.3262880614,663061200000,24380340000,278650080000,20071428938.7504,229402267544.141,193068834546.586,385134100000,376302800000
2005,1242447543857.26,1083445000000,87.2024742901,781476100000,29919960000,304195780000,26090945426.6056,265266246846.043,268402600855.057,306952300000,361030100000
2006,1353859075481.57,1261399670000,93.1706772768,903196900000,38954770000,232809480000,36294423040.6312,216910169280.665,339655467614.886,356029000000,448321200000
2007,1455253260300.12,1455253260300.12,100,1028340106626.27,55713270000,187362070000,55713270000,187362070000,413484099269.877,390475504120.436,510886323057.287
2008,1503061927458.95,1656961744055.34,110.2390868789,1215394185261.69,58252840000,162377730000,64217398897.0342,179003726846.707,498715830537.822,397469645748.566,620524420197.88
2009,1513348643542.65,1729468428699.59,114.2808985939,1276354253008.9,54168480000,121031490000,61904225698.6731,138315874353.622,414195624115.801,365381960826.093,509650082429.96
2010,1638697922673.49,1978851884596.09,120.7575757079,1475592123331.43,53750500000,75333100000,64907800730.8705,90970425265.602,527505380784.85,433869092753.816,651040957447.698
2011,1688841703851.69,2218428824292.59,131.3580082274,1233480264844.07,65218700000,11002340000,85669985311.7773,14452454682.4021,556020587537.167,525750765136.529,749797745712.548
2012,1730752476014.56,2377503668802.55,137.3682084383,1786146992638.45,318558732261.06,11832120000,437598423330.748,16253571264.2686,548109131163.141,580512510875.323,786487854482.959
2013,1834292875289.9,2558585610654.53,139.4862099244,1889709894858.51,369413000000,10100470000,515280192667.892,14088762787.5474,558352865212.123,650889248254.709,797757282239.087
2014,1959496848092.36,2786229703801.94,142.1910786187,2018227692393.27,417439800000,,593562154203.741,41485368130.1524,600017741550.596,744803898213.531,874637508968.428
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}%
  \bfseries Año & \bfseries PIB & \bfseries Consumo privado%
  \csvreader{test.csv}{}%
  {\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcolv}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```