# Why "Missing \endcsname inserted." when importing a csv with csvsimple with babel set to spanish?

Tags: babel, spanish, csvsimple

After [figuring out why my MCVE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309981/) wasn't working as expected, I think I've found a bug in either babel or csvsimple package. This compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
n,pibreal,pibnom,deflactor,c,isr,trc,tdeflactado,trcdeflactado,I,x,m
2000,1059317580733.46,393302970000,37.127956446,281965700000,10616220000,437870990000,3941585537.81615,162572550457.059,109702668399.757,139614000000,172276800000
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}%
  \bfseries Año & \bfseries PIB & \bfseries Consumo privado%
  \csvreader{test.csv}{}%
  {\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcolv}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
n,pibreal,pibnom,deflactor,c,isr,trc,tdeflactado,trcdeflactado,I,x,m
2000,1059317580733.46,393302970000,37.127956446,281965700000,10616220000,437870990000,3941585537.81615,162572550457.059,109702668399.757,139614000000,172276800000
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}%
  \bfseries Año & \bfseries PIB & \bfseries Consumo privado%
  \csvreader{test.csv}{}%
  {\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcolv}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The only difference is that the later imports the spanish babel package. Using otherlanguage environment to set the language to english allows the compilation, so the problem is between the spanish and csvsimple packages.

Answer (score 4):

The code in `csvsimple.sty` uses `\roman` in five places; since `\roman` is redefined by `babel-spanish`, this usage breaks.

You can file a bug report to the author and, in the meantime, fix yourself the issue.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
n,pibreal,pibnom,deflactor,c,isr,trc,tdeflactado,trcdeflactado,I,x,m
2000,1059317580733.46,393302970000,37.127956446,281965700000,10616220000,437870990000,3941585537.81615,162572550457.059,109702668399.757,139614000000,172276800000
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\standardroman}[1]{\romannumeral\value{#1}}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\csv@breakline@kernel}{\roman}{\standardroman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\csv@current@col}{\roman}{\standardroman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\set@csv@autohead}{\roman}{\standardroman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\set@csv@head}{\roman}{\standardroman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\set@csv@nohead}{\roman}{\standardroman}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}%
  \bfseries Año & \bfseries PIB & \bfseries Consumo privado%
  \csvreader{\jobname.csv}{}%
  {\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcolv}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have seen in my private code that I already replaced `\roman` by `\romannumeral` nearly two years ago. Unfortunately, I did not publish this since I was to concerned with other things (and then I forgot it). But I will provide an update in the near future.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Lamport's original idea was for`\roman` to be fully expandable. Alas, even `\arabic` may be at risk with some exotic language.

Comment: @egreg The LaTeX core never use `\roman` for that. I don't know what Lamport intended, but neither the LaTeX sources nor the LaTeX book says anything about the expandibility of `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\fnsymbols` and the like, except for `\value`. Even `\Roman` was no fully expandable until 1997 (and `\fnsymbol`still isn't). On the contrary, they state the numbering commands _print_ the value of a counter, and The LaTeX Comanion (1st ed.) speaks of "visual representation". Using them to generate code is a bad practice, IMO (and thank you, Thomas, for fixing it!), and not endorsed by the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [post suggesting](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22732) that the problem is related to how spanish treats roman numbers, and suggest to use `es-lcroman` and `es-ucroman`. Only `es-lcroman` doesn't present the issue, which according to [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.pdf) it just ignores roman conversion and allows latex to define them.