# Copy Output table in Jupyter for LaTex Document

Tags: tables, terminal-output

I am trying to write a report for my project in LaTex.
I am able to put code onto my LaTex Document, but I wanted to know if it is possible to import my output cell which is a table onto my LaTex document?
If not, any other suggestions where I should not create my own table for every output.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to just read a CSV file. Why don't you include that into LaTeX? We have questions concerning CSV files on this site.

Comment: @TeXnician Providing a link would be highly appreciated

Comment: Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table

Comment: Note also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html?highlight=to_latex#pandas.DataFrame.to_latex

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using pandas you can use
`dataset.to_latex(dataset.tex)` 
This would give you a latex table. Also you can just get the whole jupyter notebook as 
LaTeX code and than take what ever you want from it.
For this you could use 
`jupyter nbconvert /path/jupyterscript.ipynb --to latex`
This would give you your table and the code you needed to generate the table.