# Organising a table from an external file

Tags: tables

I'd like to create a tab containing information about music albums (for example, a column with the artist, a column with the album title, a column with a remark, etc.).

I don't want to do something like

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
Artist & Album & Remark\\
MyArtist1 & MyAlbum1 & MyRemark1\\
MyArtist2 & MyAlbum2 & MyRemark2
\end{tabular}
```

Since this is a list I will update often and I want it to be sorted (alphabetically, by year, etc.).

The way I thought was to store all the information of the albums in an external file and use it to create my tab (like for the references for example). Something like

```
@album{Name
\title='MyTitle',
\year='1968',
\artist='MyArtist'
}
```

Does there already exists a package to do this, or do I need to code it myself? If so, I take every ideas you have.

Answer (score 6):

If what you do is not more complex than you show, I simply will make a CSV file:

test.csv:

```
Artist,Album,Remark
MyArtist1, MyAlbum1, MyRemark1
MyArtist3, MyAlbum2, MyRemark1
MyArtist1, MyAlbum3, MyRemark2
MyArtist2, MyAlbum4, MyRemark2
```

Advantage: That can updated at easily convenience in any text editor, any spreadsheet, or even form the command line:

```
echo "MyArtist4, MyAlbum5, MyRemark3" >> test.csv
```

Then can be imported with LaTeX tools in different ways  (for instance, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table)). Whith `datatool` is easy sort this data:

mew.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
Artist,Album,Remark
MyArtist1, MyAlbum1, MyRemark1
MyArtist3, MyAlbum2, MyRemark1
MyArtist2, MyAlbum3, MyRemark2
MyArtist1, MyAlbum4, MyRemark2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[keys={Artist,Album,Remark}]{test}{test.csv}
\DTLsort{Artist}{test}
\begin{table} \caption{Test}
\medskip\centering
\DTLdisplaydb{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you need some more that sort a small table another alternative is load the csv file in R, manage in any way (sort by Artist, select a subset by some remark, etc.)  and then produce a table via `xtable`,  for instance.

mwe.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}\belowcaptionskip1ex 
\begin{document}
<<Mytable,results="asis",echo=F>>=
x <- read.csv("test.csv",header = T)
library(xtable)
print(xtable(x[order(x$Artist),],caption="Test"), 
      include.rownames=F, booktabs=T, caption.placement="top" )
@
\end{document}
```

If you do not kow about `knitr` and .Rnw files, install Rstudio, or alternatively load it in Overleaf as mwe.Rtex, the result must be:

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 5):

I wanted something similar, although not
in table form, for my book and other collections. I based this on `bibtex`; feed in the book database file and get it all sorted. I wrote this up as Peter Wilson, *A personal book catalogue: bookdb*, TUGboat, no 1, pp 67-71, 2016.

It is available at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-1/tb115wilson.pdf

Maybe it will give you, or somebody else, an idea or two.

Comment: +1: But is `bibtex` (vs. `biblatex`) still relevant for this?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I don't know. It's been a long time since I used `bibtex` and have never knowingly used `biblatex`. Perhaps you can tell me.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Having re-read the article I see that I did look at using `biblatex` but `bibtex` fitted my needs better.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! It always amazes me what people can do with the provided toolchain of LaTeX and friends :).