# readcsv not working

Tags: csv

I started learning LaTeX (on Overleaf) and I have to insert a table.
Due to the size of the table, for convenience I want to import it as CSV.

I replicated the same code from internet (as [Importing csv file into latex as a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table) )

With this code

```
\documentclass{book}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}{l|c}%
    \bfseries Person & \bfseries Matr.~No.% specify table head
    \csvreader[head to column names]{csv_dir/grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\\hline\givenname\ \name & \matriculation}% specify your coloumns here
\end{tabular}

\section{Some examples to get started}



\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

I got this error

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> Missing \endcsname inserted.

This is the csv, located in *csv_dir* folder

```
\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: Please provide a fully compileable document, from `\documentclass{...` to `\end{document}`. Also provide the content of the external `csv` file that you are loading. As it stands it is impossible to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Well, the only difference to the answer you linked (which works for me) is "Figures/", so is your csv in the Figures folder? And did you include the package csvsimple (you didn't provide a MWE, as maybe the header of your csv is different?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `csv` file actually start with `\begin{filecontents*}...`?

If so, please **delete** the first line (`\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}`) and the last line (`\end{filecontents*}`). They *do not* belong in the actual `csv` file.

---

The `filecontents` environment is a way to embed external data into the actual TeX file. When included in a `tex` file, when run, a modern TeX engine will extract the contents of the `filecontents` environment and dump it into a file with the specified name. This makes it easier for users to copy-and-paste when discussing code on an internet forum (such as this one): instead of pasting into two separate files that the user has to create by hand with the appropriate file name, using `filecontents` allows pasting only once into a file with essentially arbitrary name. [See this for more info on how to use it.](https://latexref.xyz/filecontents.html)

It is not meant to be part of the `csv` file in the example you linked to.

Comment: many many thanks for the answer. This is the problem! Now works
Cheers